Github access https/ssh via jump serveer
I have a php server containing my code. There is a jump server in front of it.
When trying to connect with github and make a git pull it just hangs.
I believe that https should be the simpliest way to go, however I can not seem to get any prompt to enter my password.
I've never worked with a jump server before. How can I make my set up work with github?
I tried to check out both as https or ssh via github and both hang on git pull.
In regards to ssh. I have generated a key : ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "ioannis.chionidis@mypass.gr"
and added it in the ui of github: settings-> ssh and GPG -> add new key.

Does ssh -TvJ user@jumphost git@github.com return anything?

I have not set the ssh keys on the jumphost. Will give it a try.

You could also do ssh -TvAJ user@jumphost git@github.com, but yes, you'll need to set up the original system's public key on the jumphost's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys if you haven't already.
